# Дополнение или обстоятельство?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, члены-предложения

К одному и тому же существительному можно задать разные вопросы, например, из чего и откуда. Как определить, дополнение это или обстоятельство?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вопрос актуальный, потому что дополнение и обстоятельство школьники путают часто. Я своим объясняла так:

и дополнение, и обстоятельство относятся к глаголу-действию, но дополнение - это объект действия (с ним кто-то что-то делает), а обстоятельство - признак действия (указывает на то, как оно происходит, где, когда, почему и зачем, в какой мере и степени).

Он смастерил (что?) лестницу. - лестница дополнение, объект действия.

Он взбежал (по чему?) по лестнице. - Лестница - объект, он по ней бежал, топтал её.

Он остановился (где?) на лестнице. - лестница - обстоятельство места, потому что важно не то, что он к ней прикасался, а то, что она указывает место его нахождения, а объектное значение вторично. Обычно мы говорим: обстоятельство со значением дополнения.

Если же вопрос задаётся от существительного (кроме отглагольных), словоформа не может быть обстоятельством, зато можно перепутать определение и дополнение.

Жизнь (какая? где?) в деревне меня многому научила. В деревне - определение со значением обстоятельства (жизнь - отглагольное сущ.)

Домик (какой?) в деревне мне нравился. В деревне - только определение. Дополнением быть не может, это не объект действия и не поясняет другой предмет. Здесь есть подсказка: несогласованное определение на основе управления часто можно заменить согласованным определением (домик в деревне = деревенский домик).

Название подобрали  (для чего?) для этой деревни красивое. - дополнение, объект действия "подобрали", а если будет так: Название для этой деревни подобрали красивое, то "Для деревни" будет одновременно  определять слово "название" и быть объектом действия. Значит, дополнение со значением определения.

Comment: Или определение со значением дополнения

Answer (score 3):

Лучше отдавать предпочтение смысловому вопросу. Необходим контекст. Если "Он приехал из Москвы", то, конечно же, спросим "откуда?")

Comment: А нельзя задать вопрос:"Из какого города он приехал?"?

Comment: Можно. Тогда предложение будет выглядеть так:Он приехал из города Москвы.И это будет уже определением (точнее приложением)

Comment: По-вашему нельзя на вопрос "Из какого города он приехал?" ответить "Он приехал из Москвы"?

Comment: Можно и не только по-моему. Тогда "из Москвы" будет обстоятельством.

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение, обстоятельство, определение - всё это второстепенные члены предложения, своеобразные актеры с определенной синтаксической ролью. Но вот интересно задуматься о смысле названий, особенно в тех случаях, когда можно задать два вопроса, например: дом (из чего, какой) из камня, встретились (у кого, где) у друзей.

Дополнение - это объект, на который распространяется действие, оно "ДОПОЛНЯЕТ", распространяет действие (признак)  и обычно выражается падежной формой.  Но  падежная форма может также  ОПРЕДЕЛЯТЬ подлежащее или дополнение, сравнить: Дом построен из камня (из чего, дополнение). Дома из камня (какие, определение) сохраняются дольше. Также: Дорога поднималась в гору (направление, обстоятельство). - Дорога в гору оказалась непростой (обстоятельственное определение).

Также интересно сравнить: книга этого автора (чья, определение) и автор этой книги (чего, дополнение). Понятие "книги" ясно и не нуждается в дополнении, а вот для "автора"
 желательна дополнительная информация.

В целом при решении задачи можно ориентироваться на более подходящий вопрос, а при наличии вариантов давать сложное название: обстоятельственное определение,  объектное определение, определительное дополнение.